# .net web api insert multiple same data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, webapi

What I want is to create data if the name doesn't exist in the database, however, when I test the codes by using ajax request, it will create multiple data with the same name sometimes.
I am thinking, the reason is the first data and the second data reach the database at the same time. are there any ways to solve this problem?

```
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
            return BadRequest();

        View view = await _context.Views
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(v => v.PageName.ToLower() == name.ToLower());

        if (view != null)
        {
            view.NumOfViews++;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                
            return Ok(new { view, status = 200 });
        }
        else
        {
            //not exist in db create a new one
            View newView = new View
            {
                PageName = name,
                NumOfViews = 1
            };

            view = await _viewHelper.CreateAsync(newView);

            return CreatedAtAction("Put",new { status=201, view});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a unique index on Name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to do that. You can Begin a transaction on database to lock the table for example. Or try to prevent Double requests from your Front-end (Maybe with a cancelation token by the way). Or try to disable double requests in a period of time on your Startup class.
So what do you need? This is to prevent Double clicks on your front-end?

Here is some code snippet from Dapper for Transactions for example:

```
 using System.Transactions;    
....    
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    DoYourDapperWork();
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name is uniuqe in the table, you could add the restriction on database level. Use a transaction to save value and check duplicate before savechanges.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if exists keyword to check duplicity of data before inserting in db.